# How to dump a string as bytecode

Tags: lua

So i'm making a lua script obfuscator, and i have the script in a string, i would like to call string.dump on it but it only accepts functions so i would like to know if their is any alternative, i would not like to post my code as i don't want anyone making a deobfuscator for my obfuscator so yeah, thanks for any help i get!

snippet of code:

```
local someVar = loadstringtwo.."("..asserttwothing.."("..concattwo.." ("..newasciitablevar..","..nilstringtwo..")))()";

local someScript = string.dump(someVar);
```

Comment: If you want bytecode as an obfuscation of a script, why not just compile the script with luac?

Comment: What should `dump` do here? `dump` normally returns the bytecode for a compiled chunk. Do you just want the bytecode that will be generated when you compile the given string? Because that sounds like a pretty simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what is your mean and purposes, but maybe code below will answered your question

```
local someScript = string.dump(load(someVar));
```

Comment: Yes. @Sconley254, effectively, the purpose of a script is to become the body of a function. That's what loading and running do.